# redux reducers, selected mail not showing mail contents from firebase. it returns undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, redux

selectedMail is supposed to show mail contents from firebase when a mail is opened. But it returns undefined. It doesn't show anything

```
import { createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
export const mailSlice = createSlice({
    name: "mail",
    initialState: {
        selectedMail: null,
        sendMessageIsOpen: false,
    },
    reducers: {
        selectMail: (state, action) => {
            state.selectedMail = action.payload;
        },
        openSendMessage: (state) => {
        state.sendMessageIsOpen = true
    },
    closeSendMessage: (state) => {
        state.sendMessageIsOpen = false;
    },
},
});

export const { selectMail, openSendMessage, closeSendMessage } = mailSlice.actions;
export const selectOpenMail = (state) => state.mail.selectMail;
export const selectSendMessageIsOpen = (state) => state.mail.sendMessageIsOpen;
export default mailSlice.reducer;
```